# Shrink HTML select element when selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a select element as such...

```
    <select id="<? echo $rows['itemname']; ?>" class="weight">
<option disabled selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
```

This will result in various select boxes when the PHP query is run.

Example:

```
<select id="Roast_Beef" class="weight" >
<option disabled selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="Ham" class="weight" >
<option disabled selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="Turkey" class="weight">
<option disabled selected value> -- Select Quantity -- </option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

**MY GOAL**

I would like for each select box to SHRINK when an option is selected, but I'm unsure how to use a variable properly so that each element is treated separately.

In trying different things, the furthest I have got was to shrink anything with the weight class, but the obvious problem with that is it shrinks all select boxes as they all will have the WEIGHT class element.

```
$(".weight").change(function() {
$( ".weight" ).toggle({ effect: "scale", direction: "horizontal" });   //Then you scale EVERYTHING with WEIGHT class        
});
```

Comment: cud u explain "shrink"? is it something like select the option and then the select disappears with just a statement showing selected option.

Comment: Actually, I don't want it to disappear, but just get smaller. Any idea?

Comment: by smaller you want exactly what to remain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
$(".weight").change(function() {
  $( this ).toggle({ effect: "scale", direction: "horizontal" });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` to acces current changed element instead of `$(".weight")`.

```js
$(".weight").change(function() {
  $(this).toggle({
    effect: "scale",
    direction: "horizontal"
  }); //Then you scale EVERYTHING with WEIGHT class        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Roast_Beef" class="weight">
  <option disabled selected value>-- Select Quantity --</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="Ham" class="weight">
  <option disabled selected value>-- Select Quantity --</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="Turkey" class="weight">
  <option disabled selected value>-- Select Quantity --</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `select.weight` to only target a select with that class, and then use `this` to refer to it:

```
$("select.weight").change(function() {
    $(this).toggle({ effect: "scale", direction: "horizontal" });
});
```